# Postgresql: SQLSTATE[42501]: Insufficient privilege: 7 ERROR when triggering

Tags: postgresql, yii2

I use Postgresql 9.5 in a Vagrant environment: Ubuntu 16.04 Server with the latest updates. I use a Yii2 application. Of course I know there is open issue about this problem, so maybe this is Yii2 related.

I got the following error:

```
[yii\db\Exception] SQLSTATE[42501]: Insufficient privilege: 7 ERROR:  permission denied: "RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_16773" is a system trigger
The SQL being executed was: ALTER TABLE "public"."address" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL; ALTER TABLE "public"."category" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL; ALTER TABLE "public"."customer" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
```

This error happens when I want to run Codeception tests. But I did not see any config problems. (Because when I use the app as normal user, the database operations works fine.)

I have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193487/42501-insufficient-privilege-error-while-querying-in-postgresql). But it does not work, or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497352/error-permission-denied-for-relation-tablename-on-postgres-while-trying-a-selec): but the same, no any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Only roles with superuser permission can change the foreign key triggers in PostgreSQL as it can tamper data integrity. Using a database user with superuser permission should solve your problem.

Reference: https://www.endpointdev.com/blog/2012/10/postgres-system-triggers-error/

Comment: I have tried this, but the same... no result. The most funny this is a living project, and I did not got any problem during the summers, but now... it just throws these errors.
The owner the database (user) and superuser does not matter, still got this problem.

Comment: Tried using postgres user?

Comment: yes.  It seems something wrong with the foreign keys, or I do not get why it is so special in Postgresql

Comment: @uglypointer FYI the blog post you reference has moved here: https://www.endpointdev.com/blog/2012/10/postgres-system-triggers-error/